# "Syntax Error" With my If, Else and Elif statements (Python)

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement

Here is my code:

```
print "Hello, and welcome to the Slightly Interactive Autobiography of Robbie Wood."
print "Lets get started, shall we? What chapter would you like to read first?"
chapter = raw_input("Please type either 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2' or 'Chapter 3': ")

if chapter = "Chapter 1":
    print "Chapter 1"
    print chapter_one

else chapter = "Chapter 2":
    print "Chapter 2"
    print chapter_two

elif chapter = "Chapter 3":
    print "Chapter 3"
    print chapter_three

elif:
    chapters = raw_input("Please type either 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2', or 'Chapter 3': ")

# Variables - Chapters
chapter_one = "text here..."
chapter_two = "text here..."
chapter_three = "text here..."
```

And here is the exact error message from Terminal:

```
Last login: Fri Sep  7 17:22:59 on ttys000
Robbies-MacBook-Pro:~ robbiewood$ /var/folders/y6/kx37qgbs34124ztdgb4tphs00000gn/T/Cleanup\ At\ Startup/autobiography-368756862.498.py.command ; exit;
File "/private/var/folders/y6/kx37qgbs34124ztdgb4tphs00000gn/T/Cleanup At Startup/autobiography-368756862.497.py", line 9
    else chapter = "Chapter 2":
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
logout

[Process completed]
```

Can someone please help me out with this? I am a beginner Python coder, and I am coding a 'Slightly Interactive Autobiography' for a school project.

Answer (score 7):

The second group should be an `elif`, the last one is your `else` case, and *all* of them should be using `==` for equality comparison, rather than `=` which is a variable assignment:

```
# Define these variables *before* you use them...
# Variables - Chapters
chapter_one = "text here..."
chapter_two = "text here..."
chapter_three = "text here..."

if chapter == "Chapter 1":
    print "Chapter 1"
    print chapter_one

# This one should be an elif
elif chapter == "Chapter 2":
    print "Chapter 2"
    print chapter_two

elif chapter == "Chapter 3":
    print "Chapter 3"
    print chapter_three
# And the last one is an else
else:
    chapters = raw_input("Please type either 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2', or 'Chapter 3': ")
```

Comment: perhaps also mention that the variables `chapter_one`, `chapter_two`, `chapter_three` should be declared before they are referenced?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you check if two things are equal using `==`, not simply `=` as that is reserved for assignment. Secondly, you should change your second `else` with `elif`, and your last `elif` with `else`. Also, you need to define your `chapter_xxx` variables *before* you use them. Try this:

```
print "Hello, and welcome to the Slightly Interactive Autobiography of Robbie Wood."
print "Lets get started, shall we? What chapter would you like to read first?"
chapter = raw_input("Please type either 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2' or 'Chapter 3': ")

chapter_one = "text here..."
chapter_two = "text here..."
chapter_three = "text here..."

if chapter == "Chapter 1":
    print "Chapter 1"
    print chapter_one

elif chapter == "Chapter 2":
    print "Chapter 2"
    print chapter_two

elif chapter == "Chapter 3":
    print "Chapter 3"
    print chapter_three

else:
    chapters = raw_input("Please type either 'Chapter 1', 'Chapter 2', or 'Chapter 3': ")
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `=` with `==` in your if/elif statments.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems:

**(1)** You are using the assignment operator (`=`) rather than the Boolean comparison operatior (`==`) in the expression in your `if`-statement.

Your expression in the `if`-statement has to evaluate to `True` or `False`, you can't have an assignment there.

**(2)** *Also*, you can't have an `elif` at the end of your `if`-statement, it should be

```
 if BooleanExpr:
    ...
 elif BooleanExpr:
    ...
 elif BooleanExpr:
    ...
 else:
    ...
```

I.e., if you are going to use `elif` it has to be after the `if` and before any `else`.

See the [Python doc re if](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html) for more information.